# Case statement gives group by clause error

Tags: sql, conditional-statements, amazon-redshift

The following query:

```
SELECT 
    CASE WHEN is_dog = 1 THEN COUNT(*) END AS dogs,
    CASE WHEN is_cats = 1 THEN count(*) END as cats
FROM 
    animals
WHERE
    birth_date >= '2018-01-01';
```

I get this error:

> Invalid operation: column "is_dog" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function

What do I need to change on this? I'm new to using redshift.

Comment: Write your case statements like this:  `count (case when is_dog = 1 then 1 else null end)`.

Comment: You selected an answer that doesn't work in RedShift?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That should be written as

```
SELECT count(*) FILTER (WHERE is_dog = 1) AS dogs,
       count(*) FILTER (WHERE is_cat = 1) AS cats
FROM animals
WHERE birth_date >= '2018-01-01';
```

Comment: `amazon-redshift`

Comment: Well, don't tag PostgreSQL if you don't want PostgreSQL.

Comment: You realise I'm not the OP, right? It's tagged redshift and says redshift in the question.

Answer (score 1):

The `COUNT(*)` expression won't be different in different columns or in different `CASE` expressions.  It's a count of rows, and it won't change by putting other conditions ***outside*** of it.

Also, as you're grouping all rows to a single row, you can't refer to `is_cat` or `is_dog` unless that reference is inside a aggregate function *(such as `SUM()` or `COUNT()`)*.

Bring those two facts together and you ***can*** do things like...

- `SUM(CASE WHEN is_dog = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)`

Which gives a query like...

```
SELECT
    SUM(CAST WHEN is_dog = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS dogs,
    SUM(CAST WHEN is_cat = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS cats
FROM
    animals
WHERE
    birth_date >= '2018-01-01';
```

Or, assuming the `is_cat` and `is_dog` field only has `0` or `1`, you don't even actually need the `CASE` expression at all...

```
SELECT
    SUM(is_dog) AS dogs,
    SUM(is_cat) AS cats
FROM
    animals
WHERE
    birth_date >= '2018-01-01'
;
```

Answer (score 0):

On Amazon Redshift, you probably want:

```
SELECT SUM(case when is_dog = 1 then 1 else 0 END) AS dogs,
       SUM(case when is_cats = 1 then then 1 else 0 end)  as cats
FROM animals
WHERE birth_date >= '2018-01-01';
```

Or, a shorter form is:

```
SELECT SUM( (is_dog = 1)::int ) AS dogs,
       SUM( (is_cats = 1)::int )  as cats
FROM animals
WHERE birth_date >= '2018-01-01';
```

Or if the columns only take 0/1/NULL, then:

```
SELECT SUM( is_dog ) AS dogs,
       SUM( is_cats )  as cats
FROM animals
WHERE birth_date >= '2018-01-01';
```